# python: how to split a column and add the maximum element to a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split a column of a dataframe, and add the maximun value to a new column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['1,2',3,-1,'8,9,1']})
```

`Output:`

```
       a
0    1,2
1      3
2     -1
3  8,9,1
```

`Expected:`

```
       a  maxA
0    1,2     2
1      3     3
2     -1    -1
3  8,9,1     9
```

How to solve it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to assume you mean the maximum integer value.

1. You have mixed types `str` and `int`.  So start with converting everything to strings.
2. Then you find the maximum of the comma separated strings using `int` as the `key`
3. Convert to integers

---

```
df.assign(
    maxA=
    df['a'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: max(x.split(','), key=int)).astype(int)
)

        a  maxA
0     1,2     2
1       3     3
2      -1    -1
3   8,9,1     9
4  21,111   111
```

Take note of row labeled 4.  `21,111` returns a maximum of `111`

---

#### Setup

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['1,2',3,-1,'8,9,1','21,111']})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['maxA'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x:max(str(x).split(',')))

df

       a  maxA
0    1,2     2
1      3     3
2     -1    -1
3  8,9,1     9
```

Comment: This is not accurate if OP looking for maximum integer value.  It will return 21 as max over 111.

Answer (score 0):

No pandas, just plain ol' python:

```
>>> foo = [[1,2],[3],[-1],[8,9,1]]
>>> [[x, max(x)] for x in foo]
[[[1, 2], 2], [[3], 3], [[-1], -1], [[8, 9, 1], 9]]
```